# Simple tracking app using Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing a simple app showing the position of the user on a map. When he moves, the camera follows him to keep the user at the center of the map. Everything seems very simple, here is the relevant code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    LocationManager locationManager = null;
    Location currentBestLocation = null;
    LocationListener locationListener = null;
    GoogleMap map = null;
    Marker marker = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        currentBestLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                  currentBestLocation = location;
                  if(map != null){
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 17));
                    if(marker != null) marker.remove();
                    marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(position)));
                  }


            }
          .
          .
          .
          };


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        this.map = map;

        this.map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        if(currentBestLocation != null)
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentBestLocation.getLatitude(), currentBestLocation.getLongitude()), 17));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }
}
```

However with this implementation I'm facing the following issue: although the camera follows the user movements, very often the street name layer fails to update or there's a fuzzy/blurry section that fails to update until I do a manual scroll of the map. Then the entire map updates instantly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onLocationChanged` use this code.

```
 CameraUpdate center=
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
    map.moveCamera(center);
    map.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Comment: It seems to work, but I have to try it during a car trip yet. What was the problem in my implementation? Provided that animateCamera can't be used in this context, is there a where to avoid the resulting jerky movements of the camera?

Comment: Which phone are u using(depends why it is jerking) ? Please do upvote the answer and accept it if it has helped you :-)

Comment: the transition between the old position and the new position is not smooth by using moveCamera instead that animateCamera. I guess if there is a way to obtain a smooth movement

Comment: whch device are u using ?

Comment: maybe it is not able to parse all the heavy map data, try to exit all apps